# ManyToManyField along with different additional value for each

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, django-orm

I have the following models:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    Name = CharField(max_length=32, unique=True,)

class Tutorial(models.Model):
    Name = CharField(max_length=64, unique=True,)
    Courses = ManyToManyField(Course,)
    Index = PosSmallInt()
```

There are many `Course`s and every `Course` has `Tutorial`s, but there are some `Course`s that share the same `Tutorial`s.

Now, every `Tutorial` should have a unique `Index` in the `Course` that it's inside of.

I think I should point out that the `Courses`(`ManyToManyField`) was a regular `Course`(`ForeignKey`) not long ago, which means I had duplicate `Tutorial`s, and I had this line in the `Meta` class of `Tutorial`:

```
unique_together = (('Course', 'Index'))
```

to keep `Course` from having different `Tutorial`s in the same `Index`.

But now that it's a `ManyToManyField` it's not possible.

Example:

I have the following `Course`s with their `Tutorial`s:

- C#:

  1. Syntax
  2. Conditions
  3. Loops
- Python:

  1. Conditions
  2. Loops
  3. Lambdas

(For the sake of the example please consider "Conditions" and "Loops" to have *the exact same information*.)

How can I have same `Tutorial`s in different `Course`s with different `Index`es?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `through` attribute:

```
class Tutorial(models.Model):
    Name = CharField(max_length=64, unique=True,)
    Courses = ManyToManyField(Course, through='TutorialCourse')

class TutorialCourse(models.Model):
    tutorial = models.ForeignKey(Tutorial, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Index = PosSmallInt()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('tutorial', 'course', 'Index'))
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use another Model?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your answer. And yes, for your case you need to create a new model, because you have extra logic between the models.